# Sind Fragen nach Datenbanken und anderen Tools on-topic? Bedarf es einer Klarstellung?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closed-questions

Kürzlich wurde eine [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30316/392) als off-topic geschlossen, die auf spezifisch linguistische Datenbanken ausgerichtet war (Nomen mit Artikeln, verschiedene Sprachen). Nur einer der Abstimmenden hatte dies in einem Kommentar explizit begründet, und zwar "*because it is about finding a database*".

M.E. gibt die Beschreibung der zulässigen Themen aktuell eine Einschränkung auf Fragen zur deutschen Sprache, die aber nicht darauf gerichtet sein dürfen, eine linguistische Datenbank zu finden, nicht her.

Mir erscheint eine solche generelle Einschränkung auch nicht sinnvoll. Die Arbeit mit Textkorpora in Datenbankform ist doch in der Linguistik schon seit langem üblich und aus der praktischen Arbeit nicht mehr wegzudenken. Daher sehe ich absolut keinen Grund, eine Frage nur deswegen als off-topic anzusehen, weil sie sich auf Datenbanken bezieht bzw. der Fragesteller ein Datenbank-Tool sucht, mit dem er eine bestimmte linguistische Problemstellung lösen kann. Antworten auf solche Fragen können auch über die jeweilige Frage hinaus nützlich sein.

Daher würde ich für solche Fragen wie sonst auch einen spezifischen Bezug zur deutschen Sprache verlangen. Der ist m.E. auf jeden Fall gegeben, wenn die Frage darauf gerichtet ist, eine Datenbank oder andere Auflistung von Wörtern der deutschen Sprache mit linguistischen Zusatzdaten (hier: Genus) zu finden.

Zur Abgrenzung: der spezifische Sprachbezug fehlt z.B., wenn die Frage auf eine **Fachdatenbank** (z.B. chemische oder medizinische Fachinformationen, wenn auch in deutscher Sprache) gerichtet wäre.

Comment: Ein Blick in [[tag:resources]] zeigt, dass wir einige vergleichbare, ungeschlossene Fragen haben.

Comment: Ich bin über die Close-Vote-Review über die Frage gestölpert, d.h. mindestens eine Person hat vor mir fürs Schließen gestimmt, hat aber keinen Kommentar hinterlassen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Alle Fragen betreffend Tools, die unmittelbar die zentralen Zwecke dieses StackExchanges unterstützen, sind on-topic**, sofern sie über rein technische Fragen ("Handbuchfragen") hinausgehen und sich hauptsächlich auf Sprachaspekte beziehen.

Beispielthemen:

- Linguistische Datenbanken
- Online-Wörterbücher
- Spezialwörterbücher (etymologische -, Synonym-, Fach-, ...)
- Lernprogramme
- Übersetzungstools

Comment: Danke für die Aufzählung der Beispielthemen!

Answer (score 2):

Ich gehörte nicht zu den Nutzern, welche die Frage schlossen. Ich erinnere mich aber, dass sie eine sehr verwirrende Diskussion über Englisch auslöste, so dass mir völlig schleierhaft war, was die Frage war.

Ferner glaube ich, dass Fragen mit engem Bezug zu mehreren Sprachen, zwar nicht off-topic, jedoch weit besser für die Linguistik geeignet sind. Dort finden sich am ehesten Profis, welche mit genau solchen Werkzeugen umgehen!