# Why did this question not appear in the reopen review queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, status-norepro

So we have this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30316/15318) which was closed at 2016-06-13 16:13:47 UTC according to the timestamp. There has been [some meta discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1137/392) on whether it was closed for the correct reasons (not relevant to this question) and there is also a reopen vote that I can see.

I’m pretty sure that the reopen vote was around before I went to lunch (which was some three hours ago), but even if that wasn’t the case it should still have been there for more than fifteen minutes. Typically, after fifteen or so minutes a reopen vote causes the question to be added to the [reopen review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review). However, the [review queue history](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) shows, that it has not been there yet (you need 2k reputation (10k if we leave beta) to view other people’s reviews there).

Why did it not show up? Is it a bug or something I failed to notice?

Comment: For completeness: According to the moderator timeline, the question entered the reopen queue 24 minutes after the first reopen vote was cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Meta.Stackexchange has the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151665/312026).

> This change is live now:
>
> If *you* voted to close a post, and it hasn't been edited since the time it was closed, then you won't see that post in the Reopen Queue.

In fact, the [last edit of the question](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/30316/revisions) had been *before* the question was closed and subsequently blessed with a reopen vote. And in the light of Hier’s screenshot, here is mine:

[image: Screenshot from the review queue]

Answer (score 2):

The question has (just?*) appeared in the Reopen Queue, making this Q at least partially obsolete. [image: Apparitionsss]

*) Honestly didn't check earlier.

Comment: Okay, maybe only *I* cannot see it? Because I vtc the question? Weird …